# Is APCu data stored in hard disk or ram?

Tags: php, memory, apcu

The title talks by itself. Where is APCu data stored? Hard disk or RAM?

Comment: APCU use RAM for caching data

Comment: No need to post here you can google it..https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry if this is a misuse. I have tried to google it sometimes and never found the answer. Probably don't know how to search it properly.

Comment: Well this is where google brings me to now, quick and easy question and answer, so thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

APCu use RAM as data store .

> It store cache in the PHP shared memory .